# How to handle Exceptions in Nested PHP classes

Tags: php, exception

I'm really confused as to what's the correct way of handling a class-chained exception.

For example,

I have a factory class,

GameFactory

```
<?php

namespace App\GameFactory;

class GameFactory
{
    public static function generateGame($game)
    {
        if (!GameEnum::tryFrom($game)) {
            throw new InvalidGameException(.....);
        }
       
        return new SuperMario();
    }
}
```

and I have a service class which will then be called by a controller class.

GameService

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

class GameService
{
    public function runGame()
    {
        $factory = GameFactory::generateGame($this->game);

        // do logic...
    }
}
```

GameController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class GameController
{
    public function run($game)
    {
        $service = new GameService($game);

        $service->runGame();
    }
}
```

My question is, do I need to catch it in GameService, and then in GameController?
or is catching it in the `Initiator-Class(GameController)` enough?

Comment: Normally, you set up some custom error/exception handlers for your application. If an exception is thrown somewhere that causes the application from working properly/breaks the flow, then don't catch it in your code, but leave it to the applications custom exception handler. If the exception doesn't break anything (you can continue the execution), then you should catch it on the level/scope you want to continue from.

Comment: Exception handling has little relationship to classes. You catch the error in whatever function is able to handle it best, which depends on the application design.

Comment: You can catch it wherever you want to handle the exception. That's completely up to you, and cannot be answered in a general way

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest `two` approaches:

**1.** You should always use `try...catch` block for such scenarios. This can help with the encapsulation and makes sure that *other classes (parent or else) are not responsible for errors thrown by the children or friend classes.*

**2.** Think of the `Exception Stack` to unfold in a one direction only. If you catch the exceptions of children in parent classes, then the log entries will try to make (a circle) and loop back to the caller class ( which is parent in our case). So, you should throw (display or manage those) in their respective classes.

Note:
Please note that `throw`, `catch`, `logging` and `displaying or rendering` are different from one another.

Comment: 1. You’re suggesting to catch and possibly re-throw at every level? Or not throw more than one level and always deal with the exception in the immediate parent level? That’s insane and impractical. Exceptions explicitly *can* travel multiple levels upwards. It just needs to be documented properly that a method may throw certain exceptions; whether they originate directly in the method or in a child is irrelevant then. 2. Wat?

Comment: @deceze 1. following what you are saying will kill the purpose of Encapsulation in Class implementation. 
If any class is acting as a medium for any other Class's exceptions unnecessarily, then such classes increase Coupling and dependency on others. 
While such a thing might work in simpler projects, it becomes a hassle when there are hundreds of third party packages involved. 
An example of this is when you autoload a third party package and it does not work, it throws all exceptions which belong to it - rather than passing those to the Application Boot.php file or the other dependants.

Comment: It's true that coupling increases if wildly separate packages throw each others exceptions. It makes sense to contain those exceptions and re-raise them as a specific exception of your own package. But that only applies to package-specific exceptions; if you're throwing some generic built-in exceptions, it doesn't matter where they come from. It's also a specific situation, and doesn't mean that you should _always_ and in every case catch exceptions immediately.

Comment: IMHO as far as my experience, I have not seen any instance in a web-designed application, where the Exception / error stack does not unfold from the very Originator of that Exception. 
While displaying (or logging) that stack is fine (however you want) based on the application requirement, it should not break the other rules of Encapsulation (ideally) and take care of itself first, then proceed with the throws.

Comment: The Fact that the OP is posting a GameFactory and GameService example clearly suggests that they are a beginner. Thus, the very purpose of the OP's query is to know if they need to standardize their implementation or can go with the wind and their own will. So, I said that "...they should always..." to enforce best practices.

Comment: Instilling the idea in a beginner that they should never let an exception travel more than one level also isn't very useful IMO. It's more nuanced than that.